# Change log level in Vert.x by adding a configuration file

Tags: java, logging, vert.x

I want to change the default log level in my Vert.x app, soy I have added a configuration file called *vertx-default-jul-logging.properties* to the project, and then add its root folder as a source folder in the classpath, [just like the documentation says](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_logging).

The file has this content:

```
handlers=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler,java.util.logging.FileHandler
java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format=%5$s %6$s\n
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter=java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level=FINEST
java.util.logging.FileHandler.level=INFO
java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter=io.vertx.core.logging.impl.VertxLoggerFormatter

# Put the log in the system temporary directory
java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern=%t/vertx.log

.level=FINEST
io.vertx.ext.web.level=FINEST
io.vertx.level=FINEST
com.hazelcast.level=FINEST
io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent.level=FINEST
```

Now...none of this works, the log level has not changed a bit; I can't see any debug traces.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you put this file in your `src/main/resources`? Tried this and it's working fine.

Comment: I'm getting the same problem. Using `ch.qos.logback` package and having the similar config file in src/main/resources/  just keep getting DEBUG logging from io.netty

Answer (score 3):

You need to add your vertx-default-jul-logging.properties file to the /src/main/resources folder like Marouane states.

If you programmatically need to change eg. the location of the log file you can do so like:

```
String logFile = "/var/log/my-app.log";
System.setProperty("java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern", logFile);
```